# Two rules for one model

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to apply two rules on `res_partner` table using two `groups`

Groups: `Staff` and `Manager`

Menuitems: `Customer` and 'Staff'

Model : `res_partner` for both views.

1. Users in group `Staff`  can only see `staff` menu details (read access only)
2. But they need to have full access to `Customer` ( read,write,create and unlink)
3. users in Manager should have full access to both views.

I tried below code

```
 <record model="ir.rule" id="staff_staff_rule">
    <field name="name">Readonly for staff</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('appartment.group_appartment_staff'))]"/>
  </record>
```

But users still can create,edit,read, and delete records from staff groups.

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

you should give the right domain that show only staff. when you put the 
a domain you indicate that this group is allawed to read only this records.

```xml
<record model="ir.rule" id="staff_staff_rule">
    <field name="name">Readonly for staff</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
                         <!-- put the right domain -->
    <field name="domain_force">[('partner_type','=', 'staff')]</field>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('appartment.group_appartment_staff'))]"/>
  </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be done easily using csv (security access file).
You can manage this kind of situation directly from the csv file and that file you need to add into the **openerp**.py / **manifest**.py file.

**CSV file example**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_res_partner,res_partner_user_access,model_res_partner,appartment.group_appartment_staff,1,0,0,0   
access_manager_res_partner,res_partner_manager_access,model_res_partner,appartment.group_appartment_manager,1,1,1,1
```

> **Rules**
>
> Rules are used to applied conditions on each records while they have
>   been trying to access.
>
> **Access Control List**
>
> ir.model.access / Access control list is used to manage permissions
>   (only model access whether user can read / write / create / delete or
>   not).

@Cherif Odoo has explained rules and here is the access control list. By these two way odoo manage securities.

Comment: Thanks Emipro. But me requirement is, The group `staff` should have the access to Create,edit,delete and read for Customer view , but for `Staff view` only read. Both view using same model `res.partner`.

Comment: It wll does the same thing what you just explained.

Comment: Emipro, just forget about group `manager`, consider only group `staff`.  As per your answer `access list` should be  `access_res_partner,res_partner_user_access,model_res_partner,appartment.group_appartment_staff,1,0,0,0` and `access_res_partner,res_partner_user_access,model_res_partner,appartment.group_appartment_staff,1,1,1,1`. Is it posiible?

Comment: I think, it does not make more sense. In rule you will get issue also because you want to achieve the different behaviour for same model with the same group. However you must have unique criteria (either group or any other fields).